# How to echo two pieces of information

Tags: php, echo

I have this code:

```
  if($tempPrice > 500) 
  {
    echo $tempPrice*0.038;
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'NA';
  }
```

What I want to do is put a '£' before the '$tempPrice*0.038' but not before the NA. So when it outputs it outputs '£123' with the tempprice and 'NA' if there isn't a tempprice.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: It looks like powershell script but can you clarify please?

Comment: @rightføld just normal php

Comment: @CalebB here's the full code: `<?php 
  $tempPrice = str_replace(',',"", $price); //gets rid of "," 
  $tempPrice = substr($tempPrice,2); //removes currency from the front
  $tempPrice = floatval($tempPrice); //converts to double from string

  if($tempPrice > 500) 
  {
    echo $tempPrice*0.038;
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'NA';
  }
 ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to the beginning of your echo statement:

```
echo '£' . ($tempPrice*0.038);
```

Learn more about string operators here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: If this answered your question make sure to accept the answer as correct so they can get credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the . sign you can echo multiple parts.

```
echo "£" . ($tempPrice*0.038);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate it in the first `if` statement. You can also use the single line notation, like so:

```
<?php 

echo ($tempPrice > 500) ? '£' . ($tempPrice*0.038) : 'NA';
```